# Can I return a struct which uses PhantomData from a trait implementation to add a lifetime to a raw pointer without polluting the interface?

Tags: pointers, memory-management, rust, traits, lifetime

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258359/can-a-struct-containing-a-raw-pointer-implement-send-and-be-ffi-safe/50341075) someone commented that you could use `PhantomData` to add a lifetime bound to a raw pointer inside a struct. I thought I'd try doing this on an existing piece of code I've been working on.

Here's our (minimised) starting point. This compiles ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d440ef5a51abad1ea656e965e9d5ef41&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_void, free, malloc};

trait Trace {}

struct MyTrace {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    buf: *mut c_void,
}

impl MyTrace {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            buf: unsafe { malloc(128) },
        }
    }
}

impl Trace for MyTrace {}

impl Drop for MyTrace {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { free(self.buf) };
    }
}

trait Tracer {
    fn start(&mut self);
    fn stop(&mut self) -> Box<Trace>;
}

struct MyTracer {
    trace: Option<MyTrace>,
}

impl MyTracer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { trace: None }
    }
}

impl Tracer for MyTracer {
    fn start(&mut self) {
        self.trace = Some(MyTrace::new());
        // Pretend the buffer is mutated in C here...
    }

    fn stop(&mut self) -> Box<Trace> {
        Box::new(self.trace.take().unwrap())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tracer = MyTracer::new();
    tracer.start();
    let _trace = tracer.stop();
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

I think that the problem with the above code is that I could *in theory* move the `buf` pointer out of a `MyTrace` and use if after the struct has died. In this case the underlying buffer will have been freed due to the `Drop` implementation.

By using a `PhantomData` we can ensure that only references to `buf` can be obtained, and that the lifetimes of those references are bound to the instances of `MyTrace` from whence they came.

We can proceed like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1f000c34eabff4283eaacfa87c0d89d6&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_void, free, malloc};
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Trace {}

struct MyTrace<'b> {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    buf: *mut c_void,
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'b c_void>,
}

impl<'b> MyTrace<'b> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            buf: unsafe { malloc(128) },
            _phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'b> Trace for MyTrace<'b> {}

impl<'b> Drop for MyTrace<'b> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { free(self.buf) };
    }
}

trait Tracer {
    fn start(&mut self);
    fn stop(&mut self) -> Box<Trace>;
}

struct MyTracer<'b> {
    trace: Option<MyTrace<'b>>,
}

impl<'b> MyTracer<'b> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { trace: None }
    }
}

impl<'b> Tracer for MyTracer<'b> {
    fn start(&mut self) {
        self.trace = Some(MyTrace::new());
        // Pretend the buffer is mutated in C here...
    }

    fn stop(&mut self) -> Box<Trace> {
        Box::new(self.trace.take().unwrap())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tracer = MyTracer::new();
    tracer.start();
    let _trace = tracer.stop();
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

But this will give the error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:53:36
   |
53 |         Box::new(self.trace.take().unwrap())
   |                                    ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'b as defined on the impl at 46:1...
  --> src/main.rs:46:1
   |
46 | impl<'b> Tracer for MyTracer<'b> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected std::option::Option<MyTrace<'_>>
              found std::option::Option<MyTrace<'b>>
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected std::boxed::Box<Trace + 'static>
              found std::boxed::Box<Trace>
```

I have three sub-questions:

- Did I understand the motivation for `PhantomData` in this scenario correctly?
- Where is `'static` coming from in the error message?
- Can this be made to work without changing the interface of `stop`? Specifically, without adding a lifetime to the return type?

Comment: Your example can be minimized a lot. The issue is that the compiler cannot infer the lifetime of `&mut self` in `stop`. I think that it cannot infer this, you must be explicit: `&'b mut self`, but that makes you "pollute" your trait.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore your direct question because I believe you arrived at it after misunderstanding several initial steps.

> I could in *theory* move the `buf` pointer out of a `MyTrace` and use if after the struct has died

Copy the pointer, not move it, but yes.

> By using a `PhantomData` we can ensure that only references to `buf` can be obtained

This is not true. It is still equally easy to get a copy of the raw pointer and misuse it even when you add a `PhantomData`.

> Did I understand the motivation for `PhantomData` in this scenario correctly?

No. `PhantomData` is used when you want to act like you have a value of some type without actually having it. Pretending to have a reference to something is only useful when there is *something to have a reference to*. There's no such value to reference in your example.

> [The Rust docs say something about raw pointers and `PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.22.1/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html#examples), but I perhaps got it wrong

That example actually shows my point well. The `Slice` type is intended to behave as if it has a reference to the `Vec` that it's borrowed from:

```
fn borrow_vec<'a, T>(vec: &'a Vec<T>) -> Slice<'a, T>
```

Since this `Slice` type doesn't actually have a reference, it needs a `PhantomData` to *act* like it has a reference. Note that the lifetime `'a` isn't just made up out of whole cloth — it's related to an existing value (the `Vec`). It would cause memory unsafety for the `Slice` to exist after the `Vec` has moved, thus it makes sense to include a lifetime of the `Vec`.

> why the commenter in the other question suggested I use `PhantomData` to improve the type safety of my raw pointer

You can use `PhantomData` to improve the safety of raw pointers that act as references, but yours doesn't have some existing Rust value to reference. You can also use it for correctness if your pointer owns some value behind the reference, which yours seemingly does. However, since it's a `c_void`, it's not really useful. You'd usually see it as `PhantomData<MyOwnedType>`.

> Where is `'static` coming from in the error message?

[Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/155423)

Comment: Hi Shepmaster. Youch. Seems I've really misunderstood. Now I'm wondering why the commenter in the other question suggested I use PhantomData to improve the type safety of my raw pointer? Is there anything I could have done?

Comment: The rust docs say something about raw pointers and PhantomData, but I perhaps got it wrong: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.22.1/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html#examples

Comment: @EddBarrett I've replied to your last comment. Let me know how that is.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it. I'm probably not going to use `PhantomData` at all, and instead: a) ensure `Trace` never leaks its raw pointer to the outside world, and b) that `Trace` itself only dereferences `buf` when it is safe. I think that's the best I can do.