# Worker pool design

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety, threadpool

I am trying to make a worker pool in rust. The design itself is simple, the idea is you add function pointers to a structure as tasks (assumed to be independent). Then that structure spawns a number of threads equal to the maximum amount of threads on the machine.

Each thread then acquires a task from the queue, executes it and when it is done acquires the next until they are all consumed.

In order to achieve it I tried the following:

```rs
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

pub struct ThreadPool<'a>
{
    task_queue: Vec<Task<'a>>,
    task_count: Arc<Mutex<usize>>,
}

pub struct Task<'a>(Box<dyn FnMut() + 'a>);
unsafe impl<'a> Send for Task<'a> {}

impl<'a> Task<'a>
{
    fn call(&mut self) { self.0() }
}

impl<'a> ThreadPool<'a>
{
    fn add_task<T>(&mut self, task: T)
    where
        T: 'a + FnMut() -> (),
    {
        self.task_queue.push(Task(Box::new(task)));
    }

    fn run(&mut self)
    {
        let thread_count = thread::available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
        println!("{}", thread_count);

        let mut handlers = Vec::with_capacity(thread_count);
        for _ in 0..thread_count
        {
            unsafe {
                let queue = &mut self.task_queue as *mut Vec<Task<'a>>;
                let task_count = Arc::clone(&self.task_count);
                handlers.push(thread::spawn(move || {
                    let index = task_count.lock().unwrap().overflowing_add(1).0 - 1;
                    (*queue)[index].call();
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not even compiling.

The kind of interface I would like would be something like:

```rs
 let mut thread_pool = ThreadPool {
            task_queue: Vec::new(),
            task_count: Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)),
        };

        for i in 0..100
        {
            thread_pool.add_task(move || println!(r"ran {i} task"));
        }

        thread_pool.run();
```

i.e. you register the tasks you want, each tasks captures data outside of it in the surrounding scope then it all runs.

I tried searching examples of something like this but the [thread pool example](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/second-edition/ch20-04-storing-threads.html) in the docs is very different.

```rs
error[E0277]: `*mut std::vec::Vec<Task<'a>>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> examples/06_fluid/thread_pool.rs:38:45
    |
38  |                   handlers.push(thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                 ------------- ^------
    |                                 |             |
    |  _______________________________|_____________within this `[closure@examples/06_fluid/thread_pool.rs:38:45: 38:52]`
    | |                               |
    | |                               required by a bound introduced by this call
39  | |                     let index = task_count.lock().unwrap().overflowing_add(1).0 - 1;
40  | |                     (*queue)[index].call();
41  | |                 }));
    | |_________________^ `*mut std::vec::Vec<Task<'a>>` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `[closure@examples/06_fluid/thread_pool.rs:38:45: 38:52]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut std::vec::Vec<Task<'a>>`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> examples/06_fluid/thread_pool.rs:38:45
    |
38  |                 handlers.push(thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                             ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2022-10-29-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs:705:8
    |
705 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `neverengine` due to previous error
```

Comment: The code you posted does [not produce the error you claim](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8cc72faeb1a8f882e881b6d475f7be43). Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: @Finomnis I copied the wrong part of the terminal log, that was my bad

Comment: Your problem is solved by [Can a struct containing a raw pointer implement Send and be FFI safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258359/can-a-struct-containing-a-raw-pointer-implement-send-and-be-ffi-safe), but your code is very, very bad. Specifically, `unsafe impl Send` in your code is a mistake and unsound, using raw pointer for the `Vec` of tasks is also unsound from multiple sides, `overflowing_add()` could be just `wrapping_add()` but is also unsound, and for last the `Mutex` could be replaced by `AtomicUsize`.

Comment: Do not drop into unsafe code if you don't understand every detail of what you're doing.

Comment: I'm hesitating to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258359/... On one hand, this _is_ a duplicate. On the other hand, solving this error won't give you a good or safe code.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Here you go, I added an answer for your peace of mind ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ChayimFriedman pointed out, there are many things wrong with your code.

- Most importantly, **don't** use `unsafe` to fix errors if you don't understand their root cause. You most certainly only fix the symptoms, but the root cause still exists and will bite you at a later point.
- **Don't ever**, not even inside of `unsafe`, cast a `&` reference to a `&mut` reference. This is always a bad idea and a strong indicator of that something else is already pretty wrong.
- Don't use `Arc`s prematurely. Most of the time, there are better alternatives, like [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html).
- Don't enforce `Send` via `unsafe`. Every type is `Send` by default, and if a type isn't, then there is a reason. In your case, the reason is that your task type should be `Box<dyn FnMut() + 'a + Send>`, then the entire `Task` struct is also `Send` automatically.
- Don't use `Mutex` prematurely. In many situations (of course not all of them), there are better alternatives, like [atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html).
- If you iterate through arrays via index inside of `unsafe`, make **absolutely sure** that you do not run out of bounds. Your code performs no overflow check before accessing `(*queue)[index]`.
- You never loop; currently every thread only takes the same last task and executes it. This already proves why casting a `&` to a `&mut` is a bad idea.
- Be aware of the difference between `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`. In your case, if you are sure that you only want to run each task exactly once, don't use `FnMut` - use `FnOnce` instead. All `FnMut` are automatically `FnOnce`, but not the other way round.
- Last but not least: there are very good crates for exactly this type of parallelism, like [`rayon`](https://crates.io/crates/rayon). Use those instead, it will be safer and perform better.

That said, here's two examples for possible solutions:

- Based on your code, but I changed:

  - Remove `Arc` and use `std::thread::scope` instead
  - Remove the entire `unsafe` thing and introduce a `Mutex` around `self.task_queue` instead. Use a `VecDeque` instead of a `Vec`, so we can simply pop the items out instead of having to count. With that knowledge, we can remove `task_count` alltogether.
  - Change `FnMut` to `FnOnce`, as we destroy the task object in the process and therefore have ownership over it. This will increase the types of functions we allow.
  - Fix bugs

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

pub struct ThreadPool<'a> {
    task_queue: Mutex<VecDeque<Task<'a>>>,
}

pub struct Task<'a>(Box<dyn FnOnce() + 'a + Send>);

impl<'a> Task<'a> {
    fn call(self) {
        self.0()
    }
}

impl<'a> ThreadPool<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            task_queue: Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_task<T>(&mut self, task: T)
    where
        T: 'a + FnOnce() -> () + Send,
    {
        // Use `get_mut()` because we already have exclusive access to the mutex
        self.task_queue
            .get_mut()
            .unwrap()
            .push_back(Task(Box::new(task)));
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        let thread_count = thread::available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
        println!("Threads: {}", thread_count);

        thread::scope(|s| {
            let mut handlers = Vec::with_capacity(thread_count);

            for _ in 0..thread_count {
                handlers.push(s.spawn(|| loop {
                    let potential_task = {
                        // Important: put this in its own scope, to make sure `task_queue.lock()` is
                        // released before `task.call()`. Otherwise no two threads will be allowed
                        // to execute a task simultaneously.
                        self.task_queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front()
                    };
                    if let Some(task) = potential_task {
                        task.call();
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }));
            }

            // Do something with `handlers`. Or don't, `handlers` can also be removed entirely.
            // Threads get joined automatically at the end of `scope`.
        });
    }
}
```

```rust
use std::{thread::sleep, time::Duration};

use rust_playground::ThreadPool;

fn main() {
    let mut threadpool = ThreadPool::new();

    for i in 0..10 {
        threadpool.add_task(move || {
            println!(
                "Running task {} on thread {:?} ...",
                i,
                std::thread::current().id()
            );
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
        })
    }

    threadpool.run();
}
```

```
Threads: 4
Running task 0 on thread ThreadId(3) ...
Running task 1 on thread ThreadId(4) ...
Running task 2 on thread ThreadId(2) ...
Running task 3 on thread ThreadId(5) ...
Running task 4 on thread ThreadId(3) ...
Running task 5 on thread ThreadId(2) ...
Running task 7 on thread ThreadId(5) ...
Running task 6 on thread ThreadId(4) ...
Running task 8 on thread ThreadId(3) ...
Running task 9 on thread ThreadId(2) ...
```

- Using [`rayon`](https://crates.io/crates/rayon), which I highly recommend:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

pub struct ThreadPool<'a> {
    task_queue: Vec<Task<'a>>,
}

pub struct Task<'a>(Box<dyn FnOnce() + 'a + Send>);

impl<'a> Task<'a> {
    fn call(self) {
        self.0()
    }
}

impl<'a> ThreadPool<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            task_queue: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_task<T>(&mut self, task: T)
    where
        T: 'a + FnMut() -> () + Send,
    {
        self.task_queue.push(Task(Box::new(task)));
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        let task_queue = std::mem::take(&mut self.task_queue);
        task_queue.into_par_iter().for_each(|task| task.call());
    }
}
```

Using the same `main()` as before, we get:

```
Running task 0 on thread ThreadId(2) ...
Running task 5 on thread ThreadId(3) ...
Running task 2 on thread ThreadId(5) ...
Running task 3 on thread ThreadId(4) ...
Running task 1 on thread ThreadId(2) ...
Running task 6 on thread ThreadId(3) ...
Running task 7 on thread ThreadId(5) ...
Running task 4 on thread ThreadId(4) ...
Running task 8 on thread ThreadId(2) ...
Running task 9 on thread ThreadId(3) ...
```

Last but not least, I think once you understand how to use `rayon` properly, you don't even need to write your own worker pool any more. `rayon` already takes care of all of this internally, simply use its parallel iterators ;)

```rust
use std::{thread::sleep, time::Duration};

use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut tasks = vec![];

    for i in 0..10 {
        tasks.push(move || {
            println!(
                "Running task {} on thread {:?} ...",
                i,
                std::thread::current().id()
            );
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
        })
    }

    tasks.par_iter_mut().for_each(|task| task());
}
```

```
Running task 0 on thread ThreadId(2) ...
Running task 5 on thread ThreadId(5) ...
Running task 7 on thread ThreadId(3) ...
Running task 2 on thread ThreadId(4) ...
Running task 1 on thread ThreadId(2) ...
Running task 6 on thread ThreadId(5) ...
Running task 8 on thread ThreadId(3) ...
Running task 3 on thread ThreadId(4) ...
Running task 4 on thread ThreadId(5) ...
Running task 9 on thread ThreadId(3) ...
```