# How can I return a type containing an Rc from a thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust, reference-counting

I'm spawning a thread which builds what is essentially a tree, which is needed sometime later and can, therefore, be computed in an off-thread. For the sake of example, think of a `Foo { inner: HashMap<Bar, Rc<FooBar>> }`. The thread's closure does not capture anything from the surrounding environment.

The problem is that the `Rc` makes the entire type `!Send`. This precludes `Foo` from being returned to the spawning thread. Effectively, the `Rc` "poisons" `Foo`.

I fail to see the reason why a type that is created by the spawned thread and returned still needs to be `Send`: It forces all inner types (in this case the `Rc` in the `HashMap`, in `Foo`, to be `Send`. This is unfixable from the point of view of the spawned thread.
It forces the spawned thread to use atomic counting all the time, while there is actually zero possibility for both threads to access the refcounter simultaneously.

Is there a way to return (not share!) a type that contains an `Rc` from a thread? Am I missing something in the understanding of `Send`?

Comment: The actual type is more complicated and actually irrelevant. The point is that there is an `Rc` (or any other `!Send`) deep inside the type-stack which I have no control over.

Comment: I was seeking to avoid comments to the tune of "Well, first of all if the value is `Foo` then this is not a tree but a generalized bifocal Van-de-gren graph of the second degree!"......

Comment: You can just say you have a `Foo(Rc<i32>)` — we don't need to know about the tree aspect to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [T]here is actually zero possibility for both threads to access the refcounter simultaneously.

But the *compiler* can't understand that, so you have to say "no really, trust me, I know it looks dodgy but it's actually safe." That's what `unsafe` is for.

It should be as simple as

```
unsafe impl Send for Foo {}
```

From the [Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html):

> - `Rc` isn't Send or Sync (because the refcount is shared and unsynchronized).

It's not safe to make `Rc` itself `Send` because `Rc` exposes an interface that would be unsafe if sent between threads. But `Foo`, as you describe it, exposes an interface that *isn't* unsafe to send between threads, so just `unsafe impl` it and be on your way.

Assuming, that is, that the interface *is* safe to send between threads. `Foo` can't have a method that clones and returns an internal `Rc`, for example (because you could use that to effectively "smuggle" a bare `Rc` into another thread via `Foo`).

If `Foo` is not *always* safe to send, but you happen to know that some *particular* `Foo` is safe to send, a better approach would be to temporarily wrap it in a type that is `Send`, as [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447461/3650362) suggests.

Answer (score 5):

Rust the language knows nothing about the fact that when a thread ends it can no longer have any references. In fact, it doesn't know anything about threads "starting" or "ending", either.

From the languages point of view, it's possible that one of the `Rc`'s clones is still owned by the thread. Once the type is on a thread, that's the end of it.

---

When you have something that you the programmer knows but the compiler cannot, that's a case for `unsafe` code.

I am not 100% sure, but, *to the best of my knowledge*, so long as all interlinked `Rc`s are on the same thread, it's actually safe. This *should* be the case for returning a value from a thread.

```
use std::{rc::Rc, thread};

type MyTreeThing = Rc<i32>;
struct ReturningAnRcAcrossThreadsIsSafe(MyTreeThing);

// I copied this from Stack Overflow without reading the text and
// stating why I think this code is actually safe.
unsafe impl Send for ReturningAnRcAcrossThreadsIsSafe {}

fn main() {
    let t = thread::spawn(|| ReturningAnRcAcrossThreadsIsSafe(Rc::new(42)));

    let a = t.join().unwrap().0;

    println!("{}", a);
}
```

This answer differs from [trentcl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447459/155423) in that the unsafe code has a much smaller scope — only the value that is returned across the thread is covered by it. Their answer marks the entire `MyTreeThing` type as safe to send across threads, regardless of context. This is fine, so long as you take care to know that all related `Rc`s are always moved wholesale between threads.

See also:

- [How can I guarantee that a type that doesn't implement Sync can actually be safely shared between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36649865/155423)
- [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423)